# SELECT query ordering by substring in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in a SQL Server table that has the following rows:

MyColumn :

```
1 Month
2 Week
10 Minutes
1 week
12 hours
1 days
2 month
2 day
5 minutes
1 hours
```

It is a text column that contains Priority strings.

Is there a way to make a select return this column ordered as following:

```
10 Minutes
5 minutes
1 hours
10 Hours
1 day
2 days
1 week
2 weeks
1 month
2 months
```

etc..

thank you

Comment: I think it would be a rather complex query condition. Probably, you should add another table with mapping of your strings to seconds, for example, and order based on the values in this table.

Comment: The desired ordering seems strange in that it is descending length of duration units but ascending within each group. Is that definitely what you want?

Comment: Could you have 6 weeks? And if so, should that sort above 1 month but below 2 months?

Comment: Consider storing values and units in separate columns. If you often need to produce strings made of these two things, add also a computed column to the same table: `AmountDisplay AS CAST(Value AS varchar(10)) + ' ' + Unit + CASE Value WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE 's' END` or something like that. Thus, you would store `10` into `Value`, Minute` into `Unit` and read `10 Minutes` from `AmountDisplay`. And it would then be easier to introduce custom sorting, like the kind you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT mycolumn
FROM tbl
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING(mycolumn, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', mycolumn)+1, 999),
    CAST(LEFT(mycolumn, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', mycolumn)-1) AS INT)
```

[SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/012be/11/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
order by case when patindex('%Month', MyColumn) > 0
              then 0
              when patindex('%week', MyColumn) > 0
              then 1
              when patindex('%days', MyColumn) > 0
              then 2
              when patindex('%Minutes', MyColumn) > 0
              then 3
         end, 
         cast(substring(MyColumn, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', MyColumn)) as int)
```

Comment: You'll need to extract the numeric value from MyColumn else it will sort "1 Month" ahead of "11 Months"

Answer (score 0):

```
select T4.cnt +' '+T4.name from (         
select substring(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) cnt,substring(name,CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1,LEN(name)) name from test4) T4      
left outer join (
select 1 as id,'Month' As name union all
select 2 as id,'Week' As name union all
select 3 as id,'Day' As name union all
select 4 as id,'Minutes' As name )T6
on t4.name=t6.name
order by t6.id,t4.cnt
```

You have to give all the distinct values (month,week etc..) in the order you want in the left table with "union all"